# Get the next and prev row data manipulations in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data like below format in table:

```
Id  EmployeeCode    JobNumber           TransferNo  FromDate    Todate
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   127             1.0                  0          01-Mar-19   10-Mar-19
2   127             1.0                  NULL       11-Mar-19   15-Mar-19 
3   127             J-1                  1          16-Mar-19   NULL
4   136             1.0                  0          01-Mar-19   15-Mar-19
5   136             J-1                  1          16-Mar-19   20-Mar-19
6   136             1.0                  2          21-Mar-19   NULL
```

And I want result like this:

```
Id  EmployeeCode    JobNumber           TransferNo  FromDate    Todate
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
2   127             1.0                  NULL       01-Mar-19   15-Mar-19 
3   127             J-1                  1          16-Mar-19   NULL
4   136             1.0                  0          01-Mar-19   15-Mar-19
5   136             J-1                  1          16-Mar-19   20-Mar-19
6   136             1.0                  2          21-Mar-19   NULL
```

The idea is

1. If Job is same in continuous than Single row with max id with min date and max date. For example, for employee 127 first job and second job number is same and second and third row is different, then the first and second row will be returned, with minimum fromdate and max todate, and third row will be returned as is.
2. If job number is different with its next job number than all rows will be returned.
   For example: for employee 136: first job number is different with second, second is different with third, so all rows will be returned.

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please specify how `TransferNo` is determined when rows are combined.

Answer (score 1):

You can group by jobNumber and EmployeeCode and use the Max/Min-Aggregate-Functions to get the dates you want

Comment: if i group by JobNumber than for employee 136 . job number 1.0 also get merged. and both job numbers are not in continuous.

Comment: @AmitGupta Group by *both* columns.

Comment: u should use `GROUP BY EmployeeCode, JobNumber`  to get every Employee with every jobNumer

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you will get a result from simple set-based queries. 
So my advice: Declare a cursor on `SELECT DISTINCT EmployeeCode ...`. Within that cursor select all rows with that EmployeeCode. Work in this set to figure out your values and construct a resultset from that.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a gaps and islands problem.  The solution here is to define the "islands" by their starts, so the process is:

- determine when a new grouping begins (i.e. no overlap with previous row)
- do a cumulative sum of the the starts to get the grouping value
- aggregate

This looks like

```
select max(id), EmployeeCode, JobNumber,
       min(fromdate), max(todate)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when fromdate = dateadd(day, 1, prev_todate) then 0 else 1 end) over
                 (partition by EmployeeCode, JobNumber order by id
                 ) as grouping
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(todate) over (partition by EmployeeCode, JobNumber order by id) as prev_todate
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by grouping, EmployeeCode, JobNumber;
```

It is unclear what the logic is for `TransferNo`.  The simplest solution is just `min()` or `max()`, but that will not return `NULL`.